# Altering the "Who can view the membership of the group?" setting of a group through CSOM or Web Services (2010)

Tags: 2010, web-services, client-object-model, groups

I was wondering if it's possible to alter a group's `Who can view the membership of the group?` setting from `Group Members` to `Everyone` through CSOM or through SP's web services.

Right now I am creating a group using the [AddGroup](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms774470.aspx) web service, but I can't seem to find any documentation on altering this setting. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using CSOM you can use `set_onlyAllowMembersViewMembership` to change `Who can view the membership of the group?`

Pass `false` if you want give view permission to everyone.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff411020(v=office.14).aspx

```
var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext();
var groupCollection = clientContext.get_web().get_siteGroups();
// Get the group, assuming its ID is 4.
group = groupCollection.getById(4);
group.set_onlyAllowMembersViewMembership(false);
clientContext.load(group);
clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for me and I can't tell why. I've tried altering the set_allowRequestToJoinLeave to test it out, and it wouldn't alter either. onQuerySucceeded is fired, but when I go to the group's setting page, nothing is changed. 

I am an owner of the group, and I've directed the ClientContext to the top site.

Comment: Have you tried `group.Update();` before executeQuery?

Comment: That worked perfectly, sorry should have thought of that. Thanks Amal